# Check device compatibilty with React VR and replacement text

Tags: react-360

Is there a way to check the compatibility of the device with React VR?
I.e. it is not running on old iPads.

How can I show a replacement text if the device is not compatible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can check just [WebGL support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl) because to render 3D scenes ReactVR is using three.js (and three.js is using WebGL for this).

If you want to run your project on VR devises you have to check also [WebVR support](https://caniuse.com/#search=webvr). [Here](https://webvr.rocks/#browsers) you have supported devices list.

In summary, ReactVR projects should run on all devices that support WebGL so iPads also (but I didn't check it by myself on any iOS device so can't say for sure). Problem is when you want to use VR features like for example running it on your phone in Cardboard. Then you need WebVR. That's why probably you heard it's not working on iPad because iOS is not supporting it yet (but you can find some [polyfills](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/make-reactvr-work-on-ios-devices-d2ca10c7f1a4)).